# A dough with $n$ raisins.. Probability to get at least one raisin?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> You have a dough which includes $n$ raisins. You want bake buns using
>   that dough. In order to do this, you knead the dough several times and
>   after that, you cut it so you have $N$ same parts. With these, you
>   bake the buns. What's probability that one randomly picked bun
>   includes at least one raisin?

So I first need to find out what kind of probability model we have here. At first glance, I thought this is a binomial distribution. But it's not because if you get $1$ raisin, there will be $n-1$ raisins left. For this reason, the correct model should be the hypergeometric distribution.

$$P(X=k)=\frac{\binom{K}{k} \cdot \binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

We want at least one raisin:

$$P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0) = 1-\frac{\binom{N-K}{n}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

But now, what shall I put into this formula? :p

This example has no specific values that's why I'm confused. Or is my attempt completely wrong? :o

Comment: Your (incorrect) reason for choosing a hypergeometric distribution applies to _every_ problem that actually has a binomial distribution--do you see why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binomial distribution is correct, actually, because we only consider one bun from the batch; you can consider each raisin in turn to determine whether it's in the bun you picked.  In the particular case here you should get, simply,

$$1-\left (\frac {N-1}{N}\right)^n$$

As the probability that your chosen bun will contain at least one raisin.

Comment: A simple question that would require the hypergeometric distribution is something like "a baker has a dozen each chocolate chip and oatmeal raisin cookies. If I pick three at random, how likely am I to get only chocolate chip cookies?" The difference is that picking a cookie affects the outcome of future cookie picks; this isn't true of the raisins, where each one is placed independently.